# Optical Waveguides with grating

Tags: optics, electrical-engineering, waveguide

I have some problems about mode analysis in grating-coupled waveguides,Would you please introduce me a useful book about wave propagation in these structures.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two of the best references for almost any topic on the EM theory for waveguides and optical fibers (and other devices). They both include a section on grating couplers:

**Hunsperger** - *Integrated Optics: Theory and Technology* - Springer-Verlag, 1991 : **Section 7.4**

**Tamir** - *Integrated Optics* - Springer-Verlag, 1979 : **Subsection 3.1.3**

They both offer a basic introduction into this which might be what you are looking for. If you need a more detailed discussion/analysis, check out the references that they mention in those sections.